# Jquery Add Class on sixth img

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple image inside a `div` and using a jquery function to calculate. If image if more than six, then the sixth image will be given a new `class`. Any idea how to do this ? Thanks

```js
$(function(){
 var imglength = $(".shopbar_smallimg_container img").length;
 
 if(imglength > 6){
  $(".shopbar_smallimg_container img").attr("class","");
 }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shopbar_smallimg_container">
                    <div class="swiper-nav swiper-container">
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/t.jpg" /></div>
                                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/black.jpg" /></div>
                                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/blue.jpg" /></div>
                                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/t.jpg" /></div>
                                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/t.jpg" /></div>
                                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/black.jpg" /></div>
                                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/blue.jpg" /></div>
                                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/t.jpg" /></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="shopbar_smallimg_container">
  <div class="swiper-nav swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="img/t.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="img/black.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="img/blue.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="img/t.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="img/t.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="img/black.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="img/blue.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="img/t.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$( ".swiper-wrapper div.swiper-slide:nth-child(6)").find('img').addClass("sixth");
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nfxn7pa2/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
  if($(".shopbar_smallimg_container img").length> 6){
    $(".shopbar_smallimg_container img:eq(5)").addClass('newClass');
  }
});
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_eq.asp

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use css, there is no need for any javascript

```
.swiper-slide:nth-child(6):not(:last-child) img {
  /* add style here */
}
```

Comment: `if there are more than 6 images, then target the 6th image`... this will always target the 6th image even if there are only 6 images... still you need to use `.swiper-slide:nth-child(6) img {}`

Answer (score 0):

You can add use [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) - it uses 0 based index so to target 6th `img`, you need to use index as `5`

```
$(function () {
    var $imgs = $(".shopbar_smallimg_container img");
    if ($imgs.length > 6) {
        $imgs.eq(5).addClass('newclass')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

$(function(){
    var imglength = $(".shopbar_smallimg_container img").length;

```
if(imglength > 6){
    $(".shopbar_smallimg_container img:eq(5)").attr("class","myclass");
}
```

})